# Can I retrieve the game script for Dungeon Crawl Stone Soup?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

I have the kill-screen up right now. I just finished a game that I really had fun with so I was wondering if it was possible to get the full game script somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere, depending on your install, there should be a folder called 'morgues'. Every game will leave a full dump in there as a textfile.

Comment: Also, if you want a dump prior to a game ending, hitting # will drop the current state into a dumpfile in the same folder.

Answer (score 2):

Since this game is Open Source, you can download a tarball with the full source code [here](http://crawl.develz.org/wordpress/downloads).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Sounds to me OP is not asking for code, but a transcript of his/her game.

Comment: @kviiri Well his question is kinda vague to begin with. "Full Game Script" is what I would refer to as source code. But ok. Transcript or Game Log would have a been better terminology in this case.